# Prove $M\Vdash\Box(\Box p\rightarrow p)\rightarrow\Box p$ for a model $M=\langle W,R,V\rangle$ in which $R$ is transitive and converse well-founded

Tags: modal-logic

Prove $M\Vdash\Box(\Box p\rightarrow p)\rightarrow\Box p$ for a model $M=\langle W,R,V\rangle$ in which $R$ is transitive and converse well-founded.

I proceed by reductio. So suppose $M\nVdash\Box(\Box p\rightarrow p)\rightarrow\Box p$.

Then, $M,w\nVdash\Box(\Box p\rightarrow p)\rightarrow\Box p$ for some $w\in W$.

But if $M,w\nVdash\Box(\Box p\rightarrow p)\rightarrow\Box p$, then $M,w\Vdash\Box(\Box p\rightarrow p)$ and $M,w\nVdash\Box p$.

And if $M,w\nVdash\Box p$, then $M,x\nVdash p$ for some world $x\in W$ such that $Rwx$.

But since $Rwx$ and $M,w\nVdash\Box(\Box p\rightarrow p)\rightarrow\Box p$, $M,x\Vdash\Box p\rightarrow p$ also.

And since $M, x\nVdash p $, it must be that $M,x\nVdash\Box p $

But if $M,x\nVdash \Box p $, then $M,y\nVdash p $ for some world $y\in W$ such that $Rxy$.

But since $R$ is transitive since $Rwx$ and $Rxy$, $Rwy$ also.

And so, since $M,w\Vdash\Box(\Box p\rightarrow p)$, $M,y\Vdash\Box p\rightarrow p$ also.

And since $M,y\nVdash p$, $M,y\Vdash\Box p\rightarrow p$ only if $M,y\nVdash\Box p$.

So, $M,z\nVdash p$ for some world $z\in W$ such that $Ryz$

But since $R$ is transitive and $Rwy$ and $Ryz$, $Rwz$ also and so on ad infinitum...

My question is this: just as a well-founded relation needs to have a minimal element, does a converse well-founded relation need to have a maximal element?

And so in this model I was constructing where we just have an infinite sequence of worlds at which $\lnot p$ is true there would be no maximal element and so it would contradict our assumptions that $R$ is both transitive and converse well-founded and $M\nVdash\Box(\Box p\rightarrow p)\rightarrow\Box p$?

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Yes, by definition, a relation R is converse well-founded on a set X iff all nonempty subset of X have a maximal element and R satisfies the ascending chain condition. See [ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-founded_relation)

Comment: Thanks so much.